# How to have half circle arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents}{depensezero.dat}
2010,14.0,67.0,19.0
2011,33.0,39.0,28.0
2012,64.0,12.0,24.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xbar stacked, ytick=data, symbolic y coords = {2012, 2011, 2010}]
    \addplot[fill=blue] table [y index=0, x index=1, meta index=1, col sep = comma] {depensezero.dat};
    \addplot[fill=orange] table [y index=0, x index=2, meta index=2, col sep = comma] {depensezero.dat};
    \addplot[fill=yellow] table [y index=0, x index=3, meta index=3, col sep = comma] {depensezero.dat};
    \node at (axis cs:0,2010) (src) {};
    \node at (axis cs:0,2011) (dest) {};
  \end{axis}
  \draw[->, >=latex, draw=red, red, thick, bend right=90] (src.west) to node[left, text=red] {+12\%} (dest.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

generates an arrow between two y ticks of the graph. i want to modify this arrow to have it representing a full half circle I.e the arrow should go a little bit more far to the west.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the `distance=<length>` to get it farther out as desired:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents}{depensezero.dat}
2010,14.0,67.0,19.0
2011,33.0,39.0,28.0
2012,64.0,12.0,24.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xbar stacked, ytick=data, symbolic y coords = {2012, 2011, 2010}]
    \addplot[fill=blue] table [y index=0, x index=1, meta index=1, col sep = comma] {depensezero.dat};
    \addplot[fill=orange] table [y index=0, x index=2, meta index=2, col sep = comma] {depensezero.dat};
    \addplot[fill=yellow] table [y index=0, x index=3, meta index=3, col sep = comma] {depensezero.dat};
    \node at (axis cs:0,2010) (src) {};
    \node at (axis cs:0,2011) (dest) {};
  \end{axis}
  \draw[->, >=latex, draw=red, red, thick, bend right=90, distance=2cm] (src.west) to node[left, text=red] {+12\%} (dest.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the arrow in front of the 2 and not the 0 and end in a similar manner.

Comment: @azetina: Yeah that is what I would do, but the OP started it at the `(src.west)` so I assumed that was what was desired.  Will wait for the OP to comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `controls`:

```
\draw[->, >=latex, draw=red, red, thick,controls=+(180:2) and +(180:2)] (src.west) to
       node[left, text=red] {+12\%} (dest.west);
```

so that you can change the angle and distance both.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents}{depensezero.dat}
2010,14.0,67.0,19.0
2011,33.0,39.0,28.0
2012,64.0,12.0,24.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xbar stacked, ytick=data, symbolic y coords = {2012, 2011, 2010}]
    \addplot[fill=blue] table [y index=0, x index=1, meta index=1, col sep = comma] {depensezero.dat};
    \addplot[fill=orange] table [y index=0, x index=2, meta index=2, col sep = comma] {depensezero.dat};
    \addplot[fill=yellow] table [y index=0, x index=3, meta index=3, col sep = comma] {depensezero.dat};
  \node[anchor=east] at (axis cs:0,2010) (src) {\phantom{2010}};
  \node[anchor=east] at (axis cs:0,2011) (dest) {\phantom{2011}};
  \end{axis}
  \draw[->, >=latex, draw=red, red, thick] (src.west) to[controls=+(180:2) and +(180:2)] node[left, text=red] {+12\%} (dest.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]